# Window phone app Submit "Notes to Tester" Option

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I am new at windows phone app development. Recently I have submitted my app and was uploaded in windows store. Then I found out that my app contains some bugs. So fixed it and again uploaded it on the Dev center. After the submission Microsoft reviewed the following comments.

The app must be testable. If it is not possible to test your app for any reason, including, but not limited to, the items below, your app may fail this requirement.

- If your app requires login credentials, provide us with a working demo account using the **Notes to Tester** field.
- If your app requires access to a server, the server must be functional to verify that it's working correctly.
- If your app allows a user to add a gift card balance, give us a gift card number that can be used in the testing.

I wanted to give the login credentials but could find **Notes to Tester** field. (Using Internet Explorer). Please someone guide me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I haven't updated my apps in awhile, but I kinda remember it is part of the submission process.  Like a `textarea` you fill in with additional notes before the final submission progress.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware I looked for it. Uploaded the app twice by creating new app packages. But could not see any field like Notes to Tester. Also there is a text Area called Certification Notes. I think this may be the field (just guessing). After confirmation from someone I will put my credentials there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same problem. Afi Wilkins (Windows Developer Support) gave me the solution that is:
At the step called "Upload and describe your package" press "More package options" that is at right from uploaded package name and then you will see "Certification Notes" field.
Helpful screenshot is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a534ca1b-0fe2-42c3-8203-243eafacc204/how-to-include-certification-notes-technical-exception-with-your-submission?forum=wpsubmit).